# Codeigniter 2.1 - array insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an array, that needs to be inserted into DB (every value is new row). Do I have to do coding like this, or there are other way to do this?

```
function galerija_insert($name){
foreach($name as $nm) :
$data['name'] = $nm;
$this->db->insert('galerija', $data);
endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize the number for insert queries, you can use [`insert_batch`](http://userguides.ellislab.com/codeigniter/database/active_record.html#insert) like this:

```
$rows = array();
foreach($name as $nm) {
    $rows[] = array('name' => $nm);
}
$this->db->insert_batch('galerija', $rows);
```